# Is there a clear pair of lists of [present] foreign supporters of the two (major) sides in the Libyan civil war and the extent of their support?

Tags: international-relations, civil-war, foreign-interference, libya

> The conflict pits powerful General Khalifa Haftar against the UN-backed Government of National Accord (GNA).

[Apparently](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-51166247) Turkey backs the GNA (with troops now) and Egypt plus a few other Arab states back Haftar's LNA.

> The role of foreign states in the conflict has come into focus in recent months, with Turkey passing a controversial law to deploy troops to help GNA forces in Tripoli.
>
> Gen Haftar's LNA has the backing of Russia, Egypt, Saudi Arabia, the United Arab Emirates (UAE) and Jordan.

But are these Arab countries sending material support? Is Turkey basically now engaged in a proxy war with the major Arab countries (and even with France, see below)?

And what about European countries? Do they all support the GNA (now)? I recall that not so long ago Italy and France [were split](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/analysis-french-italian-scramble-over-libya-fuels-haftars-offensive) on this (with French troops present in the regions controlled by the LNA apparently), but the more recent BBC article doesn't mention that anymore. Did the Europeans come to an agreement as to a unified position?